# Prove that $U(m) = U_{m/n_1} (m) \times U_{m/n_1} (m) \times \cdots\times U_{m/n_k}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

If $m = n_1 n_2 \cdots n_k $ where $\gcd(n_i~,n_j)=1 ~~ \forall i \neq j$, then prove that:

$$U(m) = U_{m/n_1} (m) \times U_{m/n_1} (m) \times \cdots\times U_{m/n_k}$$

where $\times$ refers to the internal direct product and when $r$ divides $m$, $U_r(m) = \{x ~~\in ~~ U(m) \mid x \bmod r = 1\}$. We already know that $U_r(m)$ is a subgroup of $U(m)$

**Attempt**: If $\exists$ a group $G$ such that $G =HK \mid H \cap K = \{e\}$ and where $H,K$ are normal subgroups, then we say that $G = H \times K$ where $\times$ refers to the internal cross product.

So, we have to show that , as a precursor to the requirements of internal direct product, the following things :

**(i)** $U(m) = U(n_1 n_2 \cdots n_k)  =  U_{m/n_1}(m)~~ U_{m/n_1} (m) \cdots U_{m/n_k}(m)$

(where if $A_1, A_2, \ldots , A_n$ are groups, then $A_1~A_2 \cdots A_n = a_1~a_2\cdots a_n ~~\forall a_1 \in A_1 ,\forall a_2 \in A_2,\ldots \forall a_n \in A_n$ )

**(ii)** $U_{m/n_1}(m),  U_{m/n_1} (m), \cdots,U_{m/n_k}(m)$ are normal subgroups of $U(m)$

**(iii)** $(~U_{m/n_1}(m) U_{m/n_1} (m)\cdots U_{m/n_j}(m) ) \cap  U_{m/n_{j+1}}(m) = \{e\} $

One conclusion which we can draw is that for any $x~\in ~U(m)~~: x U_{m/n_j}(m) x^{-1} = x x^{-1}U_{m/n_j}(m) \subseteq U_{m/n_j}(m) $

Hence, all $U_{m/n_j}(m) $ are normal subgroups.

I have little idea how to prove parts (i) and (iii) of the requirements. Help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: All of this is immediate from the Chinese remainder theorem, which gives $\def\Z#1{\Bbb Z/{#1}\Bbb Z}\Z m\cong(\Z{n_1})\times\cdots\times(\Z{n_k})$ as rings. To you want to have a proof that avoids any ring theory (i.e., not mentions multiplication)?

Comment: I have not reached ring theory as of yet , please give an alternate proof :). Thanks

Comment: Ok I think i have got this professor @Marc. Really having a bad day today, missing out on things which were long known to me.

if $m = n_1 n_2 $ such that $\gcd(n_1, n_2) = 1$ then $\exists u, v$ such that $n_1 u + n_2 v = 1$ . Dividing by $m/(n_1 n_2)$, we get : $(m/n_2) u + (m/n_1) v =1$ which means $(m/n_1)$ and $(m/n_2)$ are also prime to each other.

Let $x \in U(n)$ s.t $x \equiv 1 ~ mod ~ (m/n_1)$ and $x \equiv 1 ~ mod ~ (m/n_2)$ . By Chinese remainder theorem, this means $x \equiv 1 ~ mod ~ n$, which means $x=e$. Hence, all of subgroups are disjoint and  their union equals $U(n)$

Comment: Sir, can you please have a look over here. i have tried to prove it for the general case. < http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772511/prove-that-u-n-m-1n-u-n-m-2n-cdot-cdot-u-n-m-in-bigcap-u-n

Thanks a lot for your patience.